# How to set up Cruise Control GUI on a minikube kafka cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, minikube

I've set up a kafka cluster on minikube with linkedin Cruise Control. I'm trying to enable Cruise Control GUI by following the steps on [Cruise Control ui git hub page](https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control-ui) but it wont work.

When I curl the adress from within the pod it returns the html code from the page that i'm looking to enter, but when i try in my web browser the page does not connect. I figured i would need to expose the pod through a Service, but it also doesn't work. I also tried to change the properties on cruisecontrol.properties but nothing.

Pod's running:

```
cruise-control-cbdd6bf54-prfts       1/1     Running     2          23h
kafka-0                              1/1     Running     1          23h
kafka-1                              1/1     Running     3          23h
kafka-2                              1/1     Running     1          23h
pzoo-0                               1/1     Running     0          23h
pzoo-1                               1/1     Running     0          23h
pzoo-2                               1/1     Running     1          23h
topic-cruise-control-metrics-fjdlw   0/1     Completed   0          23h
zoo-0                                1/1     Running     1          23h
zoo-1                                1/1     Running     1          23h
```

cruise-control pod

```
Containers:
  cruise-control:
    Container ID:   docker://b6d43bb8db047480374b19671a761013a2fba39a398215276ffb456a1d9a9f2d
    Image:          solsson/kafka-cruise-control@sha256:f48acf73d09e6cf56f15fd0b9057cad36b3cee20963a52d263732bf7e5c1aae1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://solsson/kafka-cruise-control@sha256:f48acf73d09e6cf56f15fd0b9057cad36b3cee20963a52d263732bf7e5c1aae1
    Port:           8090/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 21 Jul 2020 10:32:27 -0300
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 21 Jul 2020 10:31:47 -0300
      Finished:     Tue, 21 Jul 2020 10:31:59 -0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  2
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     512Mi
    Readiness:    tcp-socket :8090 delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /opt/cruise-control/config from config (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-5kp9f (ro)
```

cruisecontrol.properties

```
configurations for the webserver
# ================================

# HTTP listen port
webserver.http.port=8090

# HTTP listen address
webserver.http.address=0.0.0.0

# Whether CORS support is enabled for API or not
webserver.http.cors.enabled=false

# Value for Access-Control-Allow-Origin
webserver.http.cors.origin=http://localhost:8080/

# Value for Access-Control-Request-Method
webserver.http.cors.allowmethods=OPTIONS,GET,POST

# Headers that should be exposed to the Browser (Webapp)
# This is a special header that is used by the
# User Tasks subsystem and should be explicitly
# Enabled when CORS mode is used as part of the
# Admin Interface
webserver.http.cors.exposeheaders=User-Task-ID

# REST API default prefix
# (dont forget the ending *)
webserver.api.urlprefix=/kafkacruisecontrol/*

# Location where the Cruise Control frontend is deployed
webserver.ui.diskpath=./cruise-control-ui/dist/

# URL path prefix for UI
# (dont forget the ending *)
webserver.ui.urlprefix=/*
```

CC Service

```
Name:              cruise-control
Namespace:         mindlabs
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       Selector:  app=cruise-control
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.98.201.106
Port:              <unset>  8090/TCP
TargetPort:        8090/TCP
Endpoints:         172.18.0.14:8090
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you already solved it?  THe service shall be exposed via minikube. What's the output of `kubectl get svc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that i had to forward the local 8090 port to the cluster 8090 port.
I solved it using: `kubectl port-forward svc/cruise-control 8090:8090`

Comment: indeed that is a workaround that allows you to achieve your goal. :)  I have posted "how it is supposed to be performed on minikube" as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Pod is only accessible by its internal IP address within the Kubernetes cluster.

To make the Container accessible from outside the Kubernetes virtual network, you have to expose the Pod as a Kubernetes Service.

On Minikube, the LoadBalancer type makes the Service accessible through the `minikube service` [command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/). Two steps needed:

```
kubectl expose deployment _deployment_name_  --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
minikube service _deployment_name_
```

for this particular case it is needed to substitute the "*deployment_name*" with "cruise-control"

This opens up a browser window that serves your app and shows the app's response.